# Why does my CountDownTimer seem to be going backward?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an app that reminds you to charge your phone if it is not used for a while. It works like this: you enter how long the phone should be idle before it reminds you. Then it starts a timer and reminds you when it finishes.

Here's my **MainActivity.Java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Defining UI elements
    public Button changeAppStateButton;
    public TextView minsEditText;

    //App variables
    boolean isAppRunning = false;
    public int secondsPhoneIsAsleep;

    public int timerDuration = secondsPhoneIsAsleep * 1000; //multiplying seconds by 100 to get milliseconds
    public int tickDuration = 60000; //multiplying seconds (1) by 100 to get milliseconds

    //Called when button is pressed
    public void changeAppState(View view) {
        Button changeAppStateButton = (Button) view;
        if (isAppRunning) { //If the app is running, stop app
            isAppRunning = false;
            changeAppStateButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPurple));
            changeAppStateButton.setText("Start Reminder");
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i("TIMER", "Timer interrupted");

        } else { //If the app is not running, start app
            secondsPhoneIsAsleep = Integer.parseInt(minsEditText.getText().toString()) * 60;
            isAppRunning = true;
            changeAppStateButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorRed));
            changeAppStateButton.setText("Stop Reminder");
            timer.start();
            Log.i("TIMER", "Timer started");

        }
    }

    public CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(timerDuration, tickDuration) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.i("TIMER", "tick");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            isAppRunning = false;
            changeAppStateButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPurple));
            changeAppStateButton.setText("Start Reminder");
            Log.i("TIMER", "Timer finished");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Setting values for UI elements
        changeAppStateButton = findViewById(R.id.changeAppStateButton);
        minsEditText = findViewById(R.id.minEditText);

    }
```

This is part of my XML:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/minEditText"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:foregroundTint="#FF0000"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="30"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/whenUntouched"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numberEditText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeAppStateButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
        android:background="#9C27B0"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alegreya_sans_sc"
        android:onClick="changeAppState"
        android:text="Start Reminder"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

This is logcat when I press the button:

```
I/DEV_TIMER: Timer finished
I/DEV_TIMER: Timer started
```

Why does the timer seem to be going backward? Why isn't it logging a message every "tick"?
Some explanation would be highly appreciated. I'm not too experienced with Android and Java.

Comment: Your comment on tickDuration seems to imply that there are 100 milliseconds in one second instead of 1000. How often is a tick intended to happen? From your code I would expect it to tick once every 60,000ms = 60s = 1min

Comment: Can you post the full `MainActivity.java`  file?

Comment: @VivekSasidharan I posted almost the whole thing except the onCreate(), but okay.

Comment: @ContinuousLoad - That's a mistake in the comments, sorry. I am multiplying by 1000 in the code

Comment: @AmethystAurora Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code specified in `MainActivity.java`

1. Doesn't initialize variable `secondsPhoneIsAsleep`, so the default value will be `0`.
2. So `timerDuration` will be `0`.
3. So `timer` is created to count for a duration of `0`.
4. So when the button is clicked, even though you read new value for `secondsPhoneIsAsleep`, invoking `timer.start()` will cause it to count only till `0` based on the earlier initialized value.
5. Hence `onFinish()` gets called logging `Timer finished`, then the `Timer started` gets logged as part of button click code.

**Solution**

If you create `timer` instance on button click then it should use the correct value of `secondsPhoneIsAsleep` and work properly. Like below:

`MainActvity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Defining UI elements
    public Button changeAppStateButton;
    public TextView minsEditText;

    //App variables
    boolean isAppRunning = false;
    public int secondsPhoneIsAsleep;

    public CountDownTimer timer;

    public int timerDuration;
    public int tickDuration = 1000; //multiplying 1 second by 1000 to get milliseconds

    //Called when button is pressed
    public void changeAppState(View view) {
        Button changeAppStateButton = (Button) view;
        if (isAppRunning) { //If the app is running, stop app
            isAppRunning = false;
      changeAppStateButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPurple));
            changeAppStateButton.setText("Start Reminder");
            timer.cancel();
            Log.i("TIMER", "Timer interrupted");

        } else { //If the app is not running, start app
            secondsPhoneIsAsleep = Integer.parseInt(minsEditText.getText().toString()) * 60;
            timerDuration = secondsPhoneIsAsleep * 1000;
            timer = getNewTimer(); // Creates a new timer.
            isAppRunning = true;
         changeAppStateButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorRed));
            changeAppStateButton.setText("Stop Reminder");
            timer.start();
            Log.i("TIMER", "Timer started");

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Setting values for UI elements
        changeAppStateButton = findViewById(R.id.changeAppStateButton);
        minsEditText = findViewById(R.id.minEditText);

    }

    private CountdownTimer getNewTimer() {
      return new CountDownTimer(timerDuration, tickDuration) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.i("TIMER", "tick");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            isAppRunning = false;

changeAppStateButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPurple));
            changeAppStateButton.setText("Start Reminder");
            Log.i("TIMER", "Timer finished");
        }
    };
    }
```

Comment: I _did_ initialize `secondsPhoneIsAsleep` — right on the line after `else`. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @AmethystAurora Yes, during button click. But by that time the `timer` is already initialized (Not started! but created) when you called `new CountDownTimer()` with the initial value of  `secondsPhoneIsAsleep` which is `0`.

Comment: @AmethystAurora Please see the updated answer. It includes an updated `MainActivity.java` file with some changes to get this working.